# Messages to another iphone sometimes green, sometimes green with 'sent as text message'

Tags: iphone, messages

I'm texting another iphone and think she has her imessage turned off and most of the time hasn't got wifi or data.

I have imessage turned on as well as wifi/data. Some of my texts that go through to her, are just green. However, others are green but with 'imessage' text above and then 'sent as text message' below. Why is this? Does this only happen when the recipient has wifi but also has their imessage turned off?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

'Send as test message' will appear when :

1. The other person is able to received an iMessage by a network connection but she turned off the feature.
2. When you want to send an in iMessage and the other person is able to received it, but you haven't a network connection.

Comment: Thanks it would be number 1, but why do some messages send green without any text that says 'send as a text message'? Is this when she has imessage turned off as well as wifi/data turned off?

Comment: I think that, her number is associate to a iCloud account, so the number can potentially be reached by iMessage. So Apple try to send the message by iMessage protocol but the feature is enable on her phone so iMessage failed and : 'send as text message'. But when she isn't connect to a network, Apple don't have to check/test if the number can possibly be reached by an iMessage, so the phone send the message directly by message.